# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset while pushing messages into Active MQ queue

Tags: java, tcp, port, activemq-classic

Client component is writing data (text) into port and server component is reading from the same port. Till this point is success.

Now server component is reading from the port and then placing those messages into Active MQ. 
Here i am facing issue like "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset"...

Server-Component code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException,IOException{  
    try{
        String input4mClient="";
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
        Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination destination = session.createQueue("QUEUE_PORT_2_Q");
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(6666);
        while(!input4mClient.equals("stop")){
            Socket s=ss.accept();//establishes connection
            DataInputStream dis= new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            input4mClient=dis.readUTF();
            System.out.println("at line");
            System.out.println("pushed data is..."+input4mClient);
            TextMessage message;
            try {
                message = session.createTextMessage();
                message.setText(input4mClient);
                producer.send(message);
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                System.out.println("exception at send"+e);
            }
        }
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            System.out.println("exception at close"+e);
        }
    }  catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }  
}
```

Note/ My observation here:

1. server component is able to read 1st one line data from port and placing into Queue
2. server component is failing at reading the second line data from Port
3. if i remove Active MQ code then component is able to read all the lines of     data successfully from client component
4. and if i have Active MQ code then process is failing at "input4mClient=dis.readUTF();" line

Thanks guys in advance.

Comment: Could it be a timing issue? Without sending the lines to ActiveMQ your code will read the lines from the socket pretty fast, but once you add the ActiveMQ part, sending the messages could take time, and maybe your client doesn't wait around.

Comment: you can move code around to work, say you can create jms connection, queue on your first message sent 
and the error says "connection reset" that means client is already closed connection

Comment: You are right Attila Repasi, i did thread sleep in client then it is working as expected. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add sleep to client app so server can push the messages to Active MQ.